# iframe - how to reproduce live camera feed from another website

Tags: html, css, iframe, webcam, live-streaming

I want to reproduce the live camera feed from http://www.falakrotop.meteodrama.gr/webcam.php. I want to display a resized (200x150) image of the live feed camera image on this website. Using iframe caused scrollbars to appear, making hard to see the (huge) image in a small 200x150 box. Is there a way to only take the live image, resize it and display it on my website (and also refreshing live)? I cannot use iframe to only use the image, as it seems to be dynamically generated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webcam seems to be offline now, but have you tried this?

```
<img src="http://www.falakrotop.meteodrama.gr/tincam1.jpg" />
```

If that doesn't work, you could try scraping it using [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).
You will get the full page then, and after that, use [preg_match](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get to the image.

I would also **highly recommend** clearing it with the webmaster / owner of the site. You would be sending a lot of requests to his/hers website.

You can find some good examples on the pages I linked to.
I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: <img src="http://www.falakrotop.meteodrama.gr/tincam1.jpg" />
works but I need 4 cams to include in my website: http://www.falakrotop.meteodrama.gr/webcam.php, http://www.falakrotop.meteodrama.gr/wxwebcam.php, http://www.falakro.meteodrama.gr/webcam.php, http://www.falakro.meteodrama.gr/wxwebcam.php. and the src for these images are the same (2 couples of the same src value), whereas the image displayed is different on all 4 pages. Is there any non-PHP way to make this work?

Comment: @webmaniacgr, you marked the quenstion as answered, did you get it working?

Comment: No, but I accepted your answer as it suggests a good way to solve it using PHP... I was hoping to solve it using iframe though... Is what you suggest the only way?

Comment: I woudn't say that it's the only way. If you can open the image directly, then that's easier. You can set the size like this <img src="URL" height="150" widht="200" />. The reload part could be done using jQuery. Do a search on that on this site, and you will find a bunch of examples.

Comment: If you visit the 4 links above and check the image names, they are the same in couples. So I can only get 2 images this way, not all 4 of them...